# Storing data in collection forms in Symfony2

Tags: javascript, html, symfony

Why do they store HTML tags with values in data-prototype instead of storing it just as values?
This leads to big amount of duplicated data.

Answer (score 0):

`data-prototype` attribute hold the html of collection item. You can get this html, insert in form and you get new collection item. You can`t store it as real html in form cause it would be sended to server spite of the fact that this field can be invisible. You can put it iutside the form using render tag and access later using js.